# ControllerAdvice for Invalid Enums in request parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, enums, controller-advice

Controller:

```
@GetMapping  
public Page<...> list(Pageable pageable, Filter filter){  
    ...  
}
```

Filter class:

```
@Data  
@Builder  
public class Filer{  
    private String name;  
    private Type type;  // Enum
}
```

Working API calls:

```
/page=0&size=20   
/page=0&size=20&type=one  
/page=0&size=20&type=two
```

Notworking API call:

```
/page=0&size=20&type=invalidEnum
```

The above API call returns no output. Meaning the response in postman is empty. If an exception is thrown, then I will be able to handle using controlleradvice... But with no output returned can anyone guide me on how I can handle it with controlleradvice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle `IllegalArgumentException`!

please refer this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-enum-request-param)

Comment: For that we need to have a converter class ryt? My doubt is can we just handle it with annotations in controller class and handling the exception in controlleradvice.

Comment: You don't need to convert that exception to custom exception!

Just handle it like this...

@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.clss)

Comment: @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("I messed up enum IllegalArgumentException", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

tried this.. Exception is not getting caught